# How to create a third degree polynomial in x and y in matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra, polynomials

I was going through matlab docs and it's mentioned that a polynomial can be created and evaluated as mentioned in this [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/create-and-evaluate-polynomials.html)

However, I would like to create a third degree polynomial in x and y. Example: f(x, y) = x^3 + y^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2.

How do we create a third degree polynomial in x and y, like the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you post is for creating a vector of coefficients for a polynomial of one variable. For two variables like you have, could you just use a function handle? E.g.,

```
f = @(x, y) x.^3 + y.^3 + 3*x.^2.*y + 3*x.*y.^2
```